# Stretchable parentheses in text labels in Graphics

Tags: plotting, graphics, labeling, style

I'm trying to annotate a plot with points of the form  $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$; my problem is that the parentheses don't stretch to cover the fraction. I think that what I want to do is to use a `StyleBox` inside the `Graphics` primitive to allow me to format the string using `SpanMaxSize`, but `StyleBox` is not a text string. I cannot figure out how to make this work. Is there an easier way?

So for example, if I use

```
Graphics[Text[Style["(1/2,sqrt(3)/2)", Black, 12], {-1.1, .8}]]
```

with the 1/2 and sqrt(3)/2 formatted in `OutputForm`, I get
[image]

Comment: Try MaTeX? `MaTeX["\\left(\\frac{1}{2}\\right)"]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In graphics, [`Text`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Text) objects render in [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm). In [`TraditionalForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TraditionalForm), parentheses are used instead of square brackets. So you can achieve what you want by using an expression with an invisible head:

```
Graphics[Text[Style[Invisible[""][1/2,Sqrt[3]/2],Black,12],{-1.1,.8}]]
```

[image]

There are other ways to achieve this behavior, but they require learning a bit about how boxes work.

Comment: Works great, but can you explain why? Why does an invisible head change the output?

Answer (score 6):

```
<< MaTeX`
```

```
Plot[0, {x, -1, 1}, 
    Epilog -> { Point[{-1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}], 
            Inset[MaTeX[
                    "\\left(-\\frac{1}{2},\\frac{\\sqrt{3}}{2}\\right)"], {-1/2 + 
                        0.1, Sqrt[3]/2 - 0.3}]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify how the new 12.2 TeX typesetting does in such a case?

Comment: @CATrevillian 12.2 doesn’t use Tex to typeset, it merely converts the Tex strings into mma boxes